# Normal distribution squared probability

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expectation

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4$ be independent standard normal random variables and $Y=X^2_1+X^2_2+X^2_3+X^2_4$. Find the probability that $Y≤3$. Enter your answer as a decimal and make sure that at least $10$ digits after the decimal point are correct.

I am confused about something. Since the normal distribution of $X$ is ${1 \over {\sqrt{2\pi}}}\times e$ should just square that for $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$ and $X_4$? And then add them up? That way I will have four variables. Any intuition as to how to proceed will be appreciated.

Comment: What does $X_{21}$ mean?

Comment: If you have not heard about the Chi-square distribution, you are probably also missing the tools that will allow you to derive it yourself (rules for change of- and addition of variables).

Comment: "the normal distribution of $X$ is ${1 \over {\sqrt{2\pi}}}\times e$ " is seriously wrong

Answer (score 3):

Your conditions imply that $Y$ has a $\chi_4^2$ distribution.  So you can just look up the answer in standard chi-square tables.

Comment: The table may not have enough decimals. However, integrating $\frac{1}{4}xe^{-x/2}$ from $0$ to $3$ is easy to do explicitly.

Comment: The question asks about 10 digits (!) of precision. Most tables in books give the values to 3 or 4 decimal places. This will require a bit more than simply looking up the answer in a table, I think.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=P[0%3CX%3C%3D3]+for+X~chi+square+with+4+dof

Comment: Yes, missed the precision bit.  In that case, look up the density of the $\chi_4^2$ and integrate.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted the sum of the squares of standard normal random variables is distributed as a [chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution). In this case, a sum of length 4 means it's a chi-squared with four degrees of freedom.
$$
Y\sim \chi_4^2
$$

The probability density function for a chi-squared distribution with $k$ degrees of freedom is
$$
f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{2^{k/2}\Gamma(k/2)} y^{k/2-1} e^{-y/2},
$$
where $\Gamma$ is the gamma function that generalizes the factorial. In your case when $k=4$, note that $\Gamma(2)=(2-1)!=1$, so this reduces to
$$
f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{4} y e^{-y/2}
$$
Now the question is what is the probability that $0<Y<3$. So we integrate the density:
$$
\Pr[0<Y<3] = \int_0^3 f_Y(y) dy = \int_0^3 \frac{1}{4} y e^{-y/2} dy
$$
You can integrate this to get
$$
\int_0^3 \frac{1}{4} y e^{-y/2} dy = 1-\frac{5}{2}e^{-3/2} \approx 0.442174599629,
$$
or as a percentage with the requested number of digits after the decimal
$$
\Pr[0<Y<3] = 44.2174599629\%
$$